# How to evaluate() and predict() from generator like data in R keras

Tags: r, deep-learning, keras

I have the following code. The data set can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qjt5o31oyqj10m8/data.tar.gz?dl=0) or [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats/data). The data set contains images categorized as `cat` or `dog`.

The task of this code is for training cats and dogs image data.
So that given a picture, it can tell whether it's cat's or dog.
It is motivated by this [page](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/blog/keras-image-classification-on-small-datasets.html). Below is the sucessfully running code:

```
library(keras)


# Organize dataset --------------------------------------------------------
#options(warn = -1)

# Ths input
original_dataset_dir <- "data/kaggle_cats_dogs/original/"


# Create new organized dataset directory ----------------------------------

base_dir <- "data/kaggle_cats_dogs_small/"
dir.create(base_dir)

train_dir <- file.path(base_dir, "train")
dir.create(train_dir)

validation_dir <- file.path(base_dir, "validation")
dir.create(validation_dir)

test_dir <- file.path(base_dir, "test")
dir.create(test_dir)

train_cats_dir <- file.path(train_dir, "cats")
dir.create(train_cats_dir)

train_dogs_dir <- file.path(train_dir, "dogs")
dir.create(train_dogs_dir)

validation_cats_dir <- file.path(validation_dir, "cats")
dir.create(validation_cats_dir)

validation_dogs_dir <- file.path(validation_dir, "dogs")
dir.create(validation_dogs_dir)

test_cats_dir <- file.path(test_dir, "cats")
dir.create(test_cats_dir)

test_dogs_dir <- file.path(test_dir, "dogs")
dir.create(test_dogs_dir)

# Copying files from original dataset to newly created directory
fnames <- paste0("cat.", 1:1000, ".jpg")
dum <- file.copy(file.path(original_dataset_dir, fnames), 
          file.path(train_cats_dir)) 


fnames <- paste0("cat.", 1001:1500, ".jpg")
dum <- file.copy(file.path(original_dataset_dir, fnames), 
          file.path(validation_cats_dir))

fnames <- paste0("cat.", 1501:2000, ".jpg")
dum <- file.copy(file.path(original_dataset_dir, fnames),
          file.path(test_cats_dir))

fnames <- paste0("dog.", 1:1000, ".jpg")
dum <- file.copy(file.path(original_dataset_dir, fnames),
          file.path(train_dogs_dir))

fnames <- paste0("dog.", 1001:1500, ".jpg")
dum <- file.copy(file.path(original_dataset_dir, fnames),
          file.path(validation_dogs_dir)) 

fnames <- paste0("dog.", 1501:2000, ".jpg")
dum <- file.copy(file.path(original_dataset_dir, fnames),
          file.path(test_dogs_dir))

options(warn = -1)

# Making model ------------------------------------------------------------


conv_base <- application_vgg16(
  weights = "imagenet",
  include_top = FALSE,
  input_shape = c(150, 150, 3)
)


model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
  conv_base %>%
  layer_flatten() %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 256, activation = "relu") %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")

summary(model)

length(model$trainable_weights)
freeze_weights(conv_base)
length(model$trainable_weights)



# Train model -------------------------------------------------------------

train_datagen = image_data_generator(
  rescale = 1/255,
  rotation_range = 40,
  width_shift_range = 0.2,
  height_shift_range = 0.2,
  shear_range = 0.2,
  zoom_range = 0.2,
  horizontal_flip = TRUE,
  fill_mode = "nearest"
)

# Note that the validation data shouldn't be augmented!
test_datagen <- image_data_generator(rescale = 1/255)  

train_generator <- flow_images_from_directory(
  train_dir,                  # Target directory  
  train_datagen,              # Data generator
  target_size = c(150, 150),  # Resizes all images to 150 × 150
  batch_size = 20,
  class_mode = "binary"       # binary_crossentropy loss for binary labels
)

validation_generator <- flow_images_from_directory(
  validation_dir,
  test_datagen,
  target_size = c(150, 150),
  batch_size = 20,
  class_mode = "binary"
)


# Compile model -----------------------------------------------------------

model %>% compile(
  loss = "binary_crossentropy",
  optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(lr = 2e-5),
  metrics = c("accuracy")
)


# Fit ---------------------------------------------------------------

history <- model %>% fit_generator(
  train_generator,
  steps_per_epoch = 100,
  epochs = 30,
  validation_data = validation_generator,
  validation_steps = 50
)


# Plot --------------------------------------------------------------------
plot(history)
```

My question is how can I [evaluate()](https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/evaluate.keras.engine.training.Model.html) and [predict_class()](https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/predict_proba.html) the data using data in `test_dir` based on the [image_data_generator()](https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/image_data_generator.html) and [flow_images_from_directory()](https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/flow_images_from_directory.html).

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
test_generator <- flow_images_from_directory(
  test_dir,                  # Target directory  
  train_datagen,              # Data generator
  target_size = c(150, 150),  # Resizes all images to 150 × 150
  batch_size = 20,
  class_mode = "binary"       # binary_crossentropy loss for binary labels
)
model %>% evaluate(test_generator, test_generator)
# Error in dim(x) <- length(x) : invalid first argument

model %>% predict_classes(test_generator)
# Error in dim(x) <- length(x) : invalid first argument
```

Comment: have you tried evaluate_generator and predict_generator? also if you use predict, you need to use class_mode=`NULL` since you don't want to pass labels

Comment: @sladomic Can you give example code?

Comment: well similar to what you already have: model %>% evaluate_generator(test_generator, steps=num_test_images)

Comment: There's another typo/issue. You use "train_datagen" instead of "test_datagen" for test_generator <- flow_images_from_directory(...)

Comment: @sladomic Thanks. I tried. It worked. But then how can I tell the class? What's the generator version for `predict_classes()` ? And the output dimension of `model %>%  predict_generator(test_generator, 100, verbose = 1) %>% dim()` is `2000 1`. How can I tell the probability belong to which class?

Comment: train_generator$class_indices gives you a dictionary of your classes (e.g. cat: 0, dog: 1). With that you can use ifelse(predictions > 0.5, 1, 0) to get the class 0 or 1 per row. You can choose the threshold 0.5 depending on your accuracy/recall trade-off

Comment: @sladomic Thanks. Please be patient with me. Based on what you define `ifelse(predictions > 0.5, 1, 0)` and not `ifelse(predictions < 0.5, 1, 0)` or `ifelse(predictions > 0.5, 0, 1)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163956/discussion-between-sladomic-and-pdubois).

Comment: @sladomic ok. Let's go there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using a generator, you should use the function evaluate_generator/predict_generator:

```
model %>% evaluate_generator(test_generator, steps=num_test_images)
model %>% predict_generator(test_generator, steps=num_test_images)
```

predict_generator will return a list or probabilites which you can turn into classes using ifelse:

```
ifelse(predictions > 0.5, 1, 0)
```

and `train_generator$class_indices` will give you a dictionary of the class indices (e.g. {'cat': 0, 'dog': 1})

Comment: Why does the model return a matrix with num_test_images * batch_size when predicting these? When I predict with steps = Num_test_images/batch_size it gives the exact number but the predictions are wrong...I need to wait for num_test_images*batch_size to predict then take the top num_test_images and these match the dataset.