# predict_generator in Keras forever run time

Tags: r, keras

Solved: per this github issue (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3946), when using flow_images_from_directory, images must be in a folder within the specified directory (folder within a folder). Discovered this based on (“Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes”) message when trying to run this code in Python. In R, no error message results, and predict_generator runs forever. After putting images into a folder (titled “folder”) within test_dir, predict_generator worked quickly (20 ms/step) and gave sensical results on images of cats and dogs.

Original post:

We are trying to use a fine-tuned model to make predictions on unlabeled image. For this example, we are using a model taken from Allaire and Chollet's Deep Learning With R (and available from their github site, link below in code). The problem we are encountering is that, even with making predictions on only one image, and working on a computer with GPU, the predict_generator part of this code runs for 18 hours without completion. We intend to make predictions on ~200K images, so we need run time to be short per image.

(Note: We think our GPU is engaged, based on it taking a few hours to fine-tune VGG on a binary classification task with several hundred training images.)

Our code is adapted from this post:

[How to evaluate() and predict() from generator like data in R keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48458470/how-to-evaluate-and-predict-from-generator-like-data-in-r-keras)

We have tried, with similar indefinite run-time results, to follow  a similar example:

https://www.kaggle.com/dkoops/keras-r-vgg16-base

What changes do we need to make to our code to generate predictions? What is a reasonable expected run time per image (seconds?)?

Here is our code:

```
library(keras)
####load cats and dogs model (taken from: https://github.com/jjallaire/deep-learning-with-r-notebooks)
model <- load_model_hdf5("cats_and_dogs_small_2.h5")

train_datagen = image_data_generator(
  rescale = 1/255,
  rotation_range = 40,
  width_shift_range = 0.2,
  height_shift_range = 0.2,
  shear_range = 0.2,
  zoom_range = 0.2,
  horizontal_flip = TRUE,
  fill_mode = "nearest"
)

#get data from https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats/data. Put one image into folder test1image
test_dir<-"test1image"

test_generator <- flow_images_from_directory(
  test_dir,                  # Target directory  
  train_datagen,              # Data generator
  target_size = c(150, 150),  # Resizes all images to 150 × 150
  batch_size = 1,
  class_mode = "binary",
  shuffle = FALSE# binary_crossentropy loss for binary labels
)

num_test_images = 1
y <- predict_generator(model, test_generator, steps=num_test_images, 
                       verbose =1)
```

Comment: You should try this directly in Python, it could be an issue with the R bindings. Also make sure that the GPU is being used. Still 18 hrs is too much.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Matias, we will try in Python and confirm GPU is being used.